# reload page from express using setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have code that

a) handles a POST route,
b) taps API to generate access token and renders a page, and
c) runs the code on interval.

The problem is the first instance works fine, but second instance I get `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT` error. My code:

```
app.post("/intervalQuote",(req,res)=>{
  MongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err,db)=>{
    if (err) throw err;
    const dbo = db.db('ameritrade');
    const ticker = req.body.ticker.toUpperCase();
    
    function intervalTimer() {
      access_token(dbo).then((access_token)=>{
        quote(access_token,ticker).then((quote)=>{
          res.render('quote',{result: quote});
        })
      })
    }
    intervalTimer();
    setInterval(intervalTimer,10*1000);
  })
})
```

I need to be able to run `access_token`, then `quote` functions before rendering the `quote` template. How can I do this on interval and reload the page? Much thanks for the help / suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

The error **ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT** is caused by sending a response several times `res.render('quote',{result: quote});` in a `setInterval(intervalTimer,10*1000);`. As per de [ExpressJS documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) says *res.render sends the rendered HTML string to the client.*

Once you've sent a response to the client you can't send another response as said [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html). The `res.render` function ends the request-response cycle.

To sum up, don't set an interval to re-render an static HTML.

Comment: Thank you Jose! I'm still at a loss as to how to proceed. If you know what topics I should cover to get an idea, it would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. Duh, my brain was frozen. All I had to do was move the setInterval function over to client side. Thanks all for looking at the question!